# Mounting a TV on the wall

Tags: mounting, brackets

I am trying to mount a 20 inch TV on a plasterboard wall. There are only two studs in the wall. One where I won't be able to see the TV and the other above an electrical socket. I do not want to put the bracket on the stud with the socket. Nothing is in line in my house, so god only knows where the cable is. The only other wall is a chimney breast. I am reluctant to mount it there, in case I get it wrong. Also my drill is a bit week when going through brick. I really want to do this my self and not ask my brother. Many thanks.

Comment: Is this an LCD TV?  How much does it weigh?  Does the mount hold it flat against the wall or is it articulating?

Answer (score 1):

Check out "togglers".  They work extremely well.  Two of them should be more than enough for a 20" TV.  Along the togglers you'll need a 1/2" drill bit.

http://www.toggler.com/products/snaptoggle/overview.php

Comment: Please explain the down vote.  As long as the TV isn't a CRT (which I believe is a safe assumption in this day and age) it is most likely less than ten pounds.  Throw in another ten pounds as a conservative estimate for the bracket and at twenty pounds we're still ridiculously below the capabilities of two togglers.

Comment: I thought non-CRT was a safe assumption too, but the OP could be from a less developed country, I guess.  And they haven't answered yet... (I didn't downvote)

Comment: It's a safe bet that it's not a CRT. There's no mention of a shelf or cabinet.

Answer (score 0):

I use "AUGER" style screw in anchors if i have a heavy load on sheetrock with no stud in the area. There are several types plastic and metal the metal ones are better (IMHO), and if renting they can be removed and the hole filled. The metal ones many times can be reused , the plastic ones are usually toast when removed.
if you google "auger sheetrock anchors" there are even videos on how to use them
hope this helps.

Comment: Normally wouldn't recommend sheet rock anchors for a TV, but if its only a 20" TV, this is probably the best solution...  Wait, this is an LCD TV right?

Answer (score 0):

While mounting to studs would be preferable, one strategy I've seen done involves getting a sheet of plywood larger than the mount and mounting this to the wall - giving you the ability to use more anchors/screws than the TV mount allows.  Perhaps adding an adhesive like [this](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/pl_ca_ptrm/overview/Loctite-PL-505-Paneling-&-Trim-Adhesive.htm) would increase the surface-contact area.  You can then mount the TV mount to the plywood.  With the glue, keep in mind that your wall will be trashed behind the board if you ever decide to remove the plywood.
The purpose of this is to spread out the weight of the mount+TV over a larger area.

Then add some decorative trim and/or paint to match.

Regarding drilling in brick, make sure you're using a (not dull) masonry bit.  That may explain why you're having trouble drilling through it.  There are also relatively inexpensive [TV mounts on MonoPrice](http://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6524) made specifically for mounting on brick/concrete (example, not endorsement).

Comment: Typically the plywood is mounted to the studs. This post didn't really make that clear.